# How to Alert and Alarm property get from EKEvent class in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

i have fetch all the events from device with its property but i couldn't get alarm and alert property in `EKEvent`

```
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentDate endDate:eventDate calendars:nil];

eventList = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
calanderDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++){
   NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]);
   NSLog(@"Event StartDate:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] startDate]);
   NSLog(@"Event EndDate:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] endDate]);
   NSLog(@"Event Notes:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i]lastModifiedDate]);
   NSLog(@"Event Notes:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i]notes]);
   NSLog(@"Event Alarms:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i]alarms]);
   NSLog(@"Event Alarms Alert:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i]alertTitle]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventsMatchingPredicate` returns an array of `EKEvent`.
The `alarms` property of an event returns an array of `EKAlarm`.

`EKEvent` / `EKCalendarItem` doesn't have a property `alertTitle`

To make it clear that's your code using fast enumeration

```
NSPredicate *fetchCalendarEvents = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentDate endDate:eventDate calendars:nil];

eventList = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents];
calanderDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (EKEvent *event in eventList) {
   NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", event.title);
   NSLog(@"Event StartDate:%@", event.startDate);
   NSLog(@"Event EndDate:%@", event.endDate);
   NSLog(@"Event Last Modified Date:%@", event.lastModifiedDate);
   NSLog(@"Event Notes:%@", event.notes);
   if (event.hasAlarms) {
      for (EKAlarm *alarm in event.alarms) {
          NSLog(@"Alarm AbsoluteDate:%@", alarm.absoluteDate);
          NSLog(@"Alarm Type:%@", alarm.type);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: in your code alarm.absolute and alarm.type both are getting null even i set both, and alarm.type not working... @vadian

Comment: Sorry, `alarm.type` is of type `Int`, so it's supposed to be `NSLog(@"Alarm Type:%ld", alarm.type);` The code is just an example to access the properties of the different classes.